# Style Sheet does not apply on first JSF page

Tags: java, css, jsf, jsf-2, openfaces

The style sheet does not apply on my first JSF page. I've got a index.jsp which forwards to my first JSF page.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <jsp:forward page="./start.jsf" />
  </body>
</html>
```

On start.jsf the style sheet does not apply but if I navigate to a second page my style sheet fully applies.

The second page was my first page before and I've had the same behaviour. Without changes, the second page works fine as long as the page is not the first one in row.

Therefore CSS and the page itself must be correct. I think it's a configuration issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should invoke the index page using an URL which invokes the `FacesServlet`. It's namely the one responsible for doing the JSF works. So you need to invoke it by `index.jsf` instead of `index.jsp`.

However, better is to get rid of this hacky index page altogether and define `start.jsf` as `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml` instead.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>start.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**and** supply an *empty* `start.jsf` file in the same folder next to the `start.jsp` file so that the servletcontainer will be fooled that the index page really exists (it namely by default doesn't check on any servlet mappings for the index page).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately this didn't solve my problem with the CSS file.

Comment: Then you need to be more clear about what exactly fails. Check the generated HTML source. Are the CSS declarations there? Are their (relative) URLs correct? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use redirect instead of forward. You can do this like this in your jsp:

```
<%  response.setStatus(301);
    response.setHeader("Location", "/start.jsf?" + request.getQueryString());           
response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
%>
```

or use

```
     response.sendRedirect("/start.jsf?" + request.getQueryString());
```

It is not best way to solve problem, I use in my project tuckey urlrewrite:

```
    <urlrewrite>
    ...
      <rule enabled="true">
        <from>^/$</from>
        <to last="true">/index.jsf</to>
      </rule>   
    ...
   </urlrewrite>
```